# Connecting SQLite 3 Database to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, swiftui, sqlite.swift

I'm attempting to open an SQLite3 database in my SwiftUI code, to access the file path within the bundle, I'm using the following function;

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    .first!
```

However I keep getting the error `unable to open database file (code: 14)`, but after trying to run it a few times I realized that the second last folder from `path` is different every time I run the code. How can I find a path to the bundle that will not change so the code works?

These are some examples of how the path changes:

Second last folder is named: `CAC91DB3-E264-436F-89A8-1E3D76C4DC56`

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EFD14A1B-7207-4840-9ACE-8E44A269CC70/data/Containers/Data/Application/CAC91DB3-E264-436F-89A8-1E3D76C4DC56/Documents
```

Second last folder is named: `0A23051F-9362-4B4D-B49B-BE0F028384DC`

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EFD14A1B-7207-4840-9ACE-8E44A269CC70/data/Containers/Data/Application/0A23051F-9362-4B4D-B49B-BE0F028384DC/Documents
```

Edit: This is the code that I am using:

```
Import swiftUI
Import Foundation
Import SQLite

func openDatabase() {
    
    let ProductID = Expression<Int64>("ProductID")
    let Name = Expression<String>("Name")
    let Calories = Expression<Double>("Calories")
    let Protein = Expression<Double>("Protein")
    let Carbs = Expression<Double>("Carbs")
    let Fats = Expression<Double>("Fats")
    let Weight = Expression<Double>("Weight")
    let Category = Expression<String>("Category")
    
    
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Database.db")
    
    let db = try! Connection("\(fileURL)")
    
    let Products = Table("Products")
    
   //Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: no such table: Products (code: 1)
    for prID in try! db.prepare(Products) { 
        print("productid: \(prID[ProductID]), name: \(prID[Name]), calories: \(prID[Calories]), protein: \(prID[Protein]), carbs: \(prID[Carbs]), fats: \(prID[Fats]), weight: \(prID[Weight]), category: \(prID[Category])")
        
        DatabaseTest().dataTest.append(Product(name: prID[Name], calories: prID[Calories], protein: prID[Protein], carbs: prID[Carbs], fats: prID[Fats], weight: prID[Weight]))
        
    }
    
}
```

For clarification on `sqlite.swift` reference:
(https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md)

Comment: Where is your database file located? Bundle and container are different places.

Comment: @Asperi I've integrated the database file into to project such that its location in my computer is ```/Users/diego/Desktop/Bites/Bites/Database```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because all applications in iOS are sandboxed. There is no way to avoid that. You can not save the full path. It will change every time you launch your App. What you need is to save only your file name and its parent directory. Use them to contruct a new fileURL and/or path every time you need to access them.

edit/update:

If your file is located inside your App Bundle:

```
let databaseURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Database", withExtension: "db")!
```

Note: If you need the database path you have to get your fileURL path property not the absoluteString. Last but not least the Bundle is read only. You need to move/copy your database to another directory ([application support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63368386/2303865)) to be able to modify it.

```
let databasePath = databaseURL.path
```

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Just don't save the path. To get the documents directory url `let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!` to construct your fileURL  `let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("yourFile.ext")`

Comment: I tried using this code but it said it couldn't find the table in the database after creating the connection, which means it couldn't find the database and it created a new one instead. I checked what fileURL returns and it said ```expression produced error: error: /var/folders/1f/102gzjts5p96d2_mzkyx27dh0000gn/T/expr5-d55158..swift:1:65: error: cannot find type 'Foundation' in scope
Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Foundation.URL>(bitPattern: 0x10f8676b0)!.pointee)```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your code? Where is your database located?

Comment: I wont ask if you did import Foundation because NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains is working

Comment: Whats is the filename of your database and where is it located?

Comment: I've integrated the database file into to project such that its location in my computer is ```/Users/diego/Desktop/Bites/Bites/Database```

Comment: You need to first turn off your app sandbox

Comment: You tagged your question as iOS

Comment: You can’t access a file located at your computers with your iOS App

Comment: But once I run the app the database is within the project so the file then should be within the device where the app is running, am I wrong to assume this?

Comment: Did you copy the database to your project and marked copy if needed?

Comment: Note that a file located in your bundle won’t be in the document directory

Comment: I did copy it into the project and marked that option. How can I then access the file from within the app?

Comment: @DiegoGonzalez `let databaseURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Database", withExtension: "db")!` and use its path `databaseURL.path`

Comment: I've tried this. Now it says it's unable to open the database. It gives me the path ``"/Users/diego/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EFD14A1B-7207-4840-9ACE-8E44A269CC70/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6B27A441-C5FF-464F-9A70-CE6A4A6D8BBC/Bites.app/Database.db```. If the path is correct then why is this error happening?

Comment: Sorry just realized this looks like you are running this on the emulator. Did you check if the file exists? Are you sure your database is not corrupted? Did you try to load its data?

Comment: Yeah the file is correctly located in the path denoted by ```databaseURL.path``` and it can be opened effectively. What do you mean by loading its data?

Comment: `let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL)`

Comment: I'm now trying to run it on an iPhone as opposed to the emulator. But once again, the location where it's looking for is different every time so it can't find the file and therefore creates a new one. How can I find the right path to the file within the phone I'm running it on?

Comment: It is already posted on my answer. Using bundle method url for resource